# How to create a spherical lithophane

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I'm trying to create a spherical lithophane in Blender 2.80 for 3d printing. I can create a sphere and hollow it out, but the inside of the sphere has the same texture as the outside (For a lithophane one side of the surface has to be smooth). I have created the sphere used displacement to create the surface texture, and then subtracted a smaller sphere from it to hollow it out. Trouble is the hollowed sphere then has the same texture as the outside. I hope this makes sense to somebody and you can let me know where I am going wrong.
Cheers
Dave

Answer (score 1):

Create vertex groups - go into the weight editing mode, select the outer part <kbd>L</kbd> and assign a weight to it <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> (when vertices are selected).
And select this group in displacement modifier

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go and report back on how it went.